# Pulumi C# Unable to convert Output<Object>

Tags: c#, pulumi, pulumi-azure

Cannot implicitly convert type Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup to Pulumi.Output<Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iitV0.png)

```
public GenerateResourceGroup(Input<string> location, string rgName, Dictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        var config = new Pulumi.Config();
        var rg = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup(rgName, new Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroupArgs
        {
            Location = location,
            ResourceGroupName = rgName,
            Tags = tags,
        });
        //resourceGroupName = resourceGroup.Name.Apply(t => $"{t}");
        //ERROR Next Line: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup to Pulumi.Output<Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup>
        resourceGroup = rg;
    }
    //[Output]
    //public Output<ResourceGroup> resourceGroupName { get; }
    [Output]
    public Output<ResourceGroup> resourceGroup { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you it cannot implicitly convert a non-output type to an output. `Output<T> != T` or in this case,

```
Output<Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup> != Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup
```

To answer your question, you need to wrap the ResourceGroup in an output, such as:

```
resourceGroup = Output.Create(rg)
```